# How can I use `class` as a keyword argument?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to write Rails helpers with a `class` keyword argument, like so:

```
special_link_tag body, url, class: 'special'
```

I can't refer to the `class` keyword because `class` is a reserved word:

```
def special_link_tag body, url, class: 'special'
  class ||= 'whatever' # error! 'class' is reserved
  :etc
end
```

I see two options:

```
def special_link_tag(body, url, klass: 'special')
  klass ||= 'whatever'
  :etc
end

def special_link_tag(body, url, **options)
  klass = options[:class]
  klass ||= 'whatever'
  :etc
end
```

I like neither of them. The first is inconsistent with Rails helpers. The second is better, but not ideal because now I need to explicitly check for keyword arguments I don't support or risk failing silently. Am I missing anything, or is the second method the way to go here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since Ruby 2.1 you can access even a keyword argument named `class` with [Binding#local_variable_get](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_get) like so:

```
def special_link_tag(body, url, class: 'special')
  "class = " + binding.local_variable_get(:class)
end
```

Comment: Still not pretty but much better than using `klass`. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It's a reserved word, so you cannot use it as a variable, a method or argument name, same as others like `if` or `for`.

Instead of `klass`, which I agree is tacky, why not be more specific:

```
def special_link_tag(body, url, css_class: 'special')
  css_class ||= 'whatever'
end
```

You can use hash-style arguments without issue, so if you're really set on a method call with `class: '...'` then you might want to use those rather than a keyword-argument-style definition.

```
def special_link_tag(body, url, options = nil)
  options ||= { }
  options[:class] ||= 'whatever'
end
```

Comment: @cthulhu I also prefer the `css_class` style of naming. Class is such a generic term that is likely to be confused, both by programmers other than yourself and even by yourself with the passage of time.

Comment: Actually, at least in my Ruby (2.1.6), you *can* use `class` (or `if` or `for`) as a keyword argument without raising an error -- you just can't subsequently refer to it in the body of the method. Which, I'll grant you, makes it a pretty worthless argument.